# javascript error: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object error using expected_conditions with Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition, selenium-webdriver-python

I have some  code in selenium/python, which used to work, But now I'm getting:

```
javascript error: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

I don't know if it's something that was changed in the angular application, or how this error is relevant to what I'm doing.
I get it after trying to locate a webelement or waiting for visibility of element, like:

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(leftNav_page.pageSmallTitle))
```

"pageSmallTitle" is just a locator like:

```
pageSmallTitle = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[id$='componentTitle']")
```

Tried changing it to xpath, but didn't make a difference.

I would highly appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

[*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) accepts a *locator* as an argument and the expression is as follows:

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[id$='componentTitle']")))
```

In your usecase, if:

```
pageSmallTitle = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[id$='componentTitle']")
```

the effective line of code must have been:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(pageSmallTitle))
```

so essentially there is an additional parameter as *`leftNav_page`*. Hence you see the error.

Removing the extra parameter will solve the issue.

Comment: No, because leftNav_page is just the class I'm taking the pageSmallTitle  from. It's the same for all other locators which work